# Java - Use of nonpublic class from the current package makes compiling error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac, java-package

I've the following two source files

File World.java

```
package planets;

public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mars.land();
    }
}
```

File Moon.java

```
package planets;

public class Moon {
    public static void land() {
        System.out.println("Hello Moon");
    }
}

class Mars {
    public static void land() {
        System.out.println("Hello Mars");
    }
}
```

As we can see, the `Moon.java` contains two classes: the public `Moon` class and the nonpublic `Mars` class.

The files are located inside `planets` directory, below is showed the directory tree

```
+current-dir:
+----+planets:
      +----+World.java
      +----+Moon.java
```

Now, if I try to compile from Windows command prompt (I'm inside `current-dir` folder) typing

```
javac planets\World.java
```

I receive this error message:

```
planets\World.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
       Mars.land();
       ^
  symbol:   variable Mars
  location: class World
1 error
```

It's very strange, because I know that the compiler searches for nonpublic classes inside all the source files of the current package.
Also Cay Horstmann's *Core Java Vol 1, 10th ed.* at pp. 192-193 says that:

> [...]you can import nonpublic classes from the current package. These
>   classes may be defined in source files with different names. If you
>   import a class from the current package, the compiler searches all
>   source files of the current package to see which one defines the
>   class.

In addition I tried to write these files using Eclipse Oxygen and it compile without problems. But I know that Eclipse use a different compiler.

Why does `javac` compiler fail?

EDIT: I have not set `CLASSPATH` variable. So by default compiler looks inside current directory.

Comment: Try making a seperate file for Mars. I don't think Java supports having 2 top level classes in one file.

Comment: Thank you for describing the problem so clearly and precisely. You need to add the current directory to the classpath, which you can do by specifying `-cp .` when you compile and run the program.

Comment: @Pshemo Just tried, same error because `.` is default classpath dir

Comment: Try compiling all the source files at once with `javac planets\*.java`

Comment: Compile first `javac -cp . planets\Moon.java` then `javac -cp . planets\World.java`. Or better use @Jesper advice if you want to avoid this ordering.

Comment: @Jesper I tried, it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you add `-cp .` to Jesper's solution, like `javac -cp . planets\*.java`?

Comment: `javac -cp . planets\*` works. Now I would know why.

Comment: I know that, if not set, compiler looks always for files in the current dir, so `-cp .` seems to me redundant. EDIT: Infact it also works using `javac planets\*.java` as @Jesper suggested

Comment: @MrKickkiller Actually it is fully supported, though it’s not good practice.

Comment: However, what Horstrmann says does not actually matches what compiler does. Because things to work need that I have to compile `Moon.java` manually so that `Mars` class is already "visible" by compiler

Answer (score 0):

you need to type the following commands in order (inside your 'current-dir')

1. javac planets\Moon.java
2. javac -cp . planets\World.java
3. java -cp . planets.World

Comment: `-cp .` is redundant. By default compiler always look inside the current directory

Comment: @Vin if you try to remove it, the compiler will fail

Comment: Nope, as I wrote in another comment it works if I type `javac planets\*.java`.